# Is it ok to supply 24 volt from the power supply with output 24 v 10 Amps to sensor which current & Voltage consumption (max) is 12-30V 35mA

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, current, sensor

Is it ok to supply 24 volts from the power supply with output 24 v 10 Amps to my sensor which voltage supply range+Vs is 12-30 V and current consumption (max) is 35mA, will current output from the power supply (10A) will destroy my sensor ??

Comment: If you connect a 6 W tail lamp that needs 0.5 A to your car's 12 V battery that can supply > 100 A will the current output from the battery destroy your bulb?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the linked question; if your sensor only requires 24V at 35mA (0.035A), it will only draw 35mA from the power supply, even if the power supply is capable up providing up to a limit of 10A. Supply volts must match load volts requirement, but as long as the supply amps limit is greater than the load amps requirement, the load will draw only what it requires. This is one of our most frequently asked questions -- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings?noredirect=1&lq=1